# How to fix android run time error in Stripe Terminal discover device code build using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe terminal code with my android app build using kotlin, unfortunately I am getting the following run time error which I could not able to fix

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: initTerminal must be called before attempting to get the instance`

The code I have added is used below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_screen)
    onDiscoverReaders()
}


fun onDiscoverReaders() {
    val config = DiscoveryConfiguration(
        timeout         = 0,
        discoveryMethod = DiscoveryMethod.LOCAL_MOBILE,
        isSimulated     = false,
        location        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    )
    // Save this cancelable to an instance variable
    discoveryCancelable = Terminal.getInstance().discoverReaders(config,

        discoveryListener = object : DiscoveryListener {
            override fun onUpdateDiscoveredReaders(readers: List<Reader>) {

            }
        }

        , object : Callback {
        override fun onSuccess() {
            println("Finished discovering readers")
        }

        override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
}
```

I have added this to one of my activity and my intention is to check if my phone is supporting [stripe tap on mobile](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=android&reader-type=tap-on-mobile)

I guess the issue could be calling onDiscoverReaders() from a wrong place, someone please help me to fix this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before connecting to the reader, you app should setup Stripe terminal SDK with the steps as mentioned in the doc [here](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-integration).

Answer (score 1):

In stripe docs you can [check](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-integration?terminal-sdk-platform=android)

```
  // Create your listener object. Override any methods that you want to be notified about
val listener = object : TerminalListener {
}

// Choose the level of messages that should be logged to your console
val logLevel = LogLevel.VERBOSE

// Create your token provider.
val tokenProvider = TokenProvider()

// Pass in the current application context, your desired logging level, your token provider, and the listener you created
if (!Terminal.isInitialized()) {
    Terminal.initTerminal(applicationContext, logLevel, tokenProvider, listener)
}

// Since the Terminal is a singleton, you can call getInstance whenever you need it
Terminal.getInstance()
```

might be you missed to initialise terminal before getting Instance so try add above code before `onDiscoverReaders()`

Comment: Getting different errors like TokenProvider not found error on object also, Screenshot is https://ibb.co/16KjRpr  . Is this any version issue?

Comment: Some changes I can see in the library https://stripe.dev/stripe-terminal-android/core/modules/core/com.stripe.stripeterminal/-terminal/-companion/init-terminal.html

Comment: seems you didn't properly setup `stripe` to your project go  through mentioned link you can find `TokenProvider` class file

Comment: Now I am struck with the error `Account not enabled for Tap on Mobile functionality ` Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: please post as new question on SO with more detailed observations

Comment: I have posted it as a new SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363974/android-stripe-terminal-got-struck-with-the-error-account-not-enabled-for-tap-on/74371800#74371800  , But I could'nt get a solution for the same till now

Answer (score 1):

The error speaks for itself - **first you need to initialize the api terminal**, and **then call the terminal instance**.

Based on the documentation, we follow the following steps to get started with the api terminal:

- *Initialize the terminal application in the application class of the
  application*

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        TerminalApplicationDelegate.onCreate(this)
    }
}
```

- *We request the necessary permissions for correct work with the
  terminal search (bluetooth, geolocation), if everything is provided,
  we call the init terminal with parameters like that:*

```
Terminal.initTerminal(
            context = context,
            logLevel = LogLevel.VERBOSE,
            tokenProvider = TokenProvider(),
            listener = object : TerminalListener {
                override fun onUnexpectedReaderDisconnect(reader: Reader) {
                    Log.d("log", "onUnexpectedReaderDisconnect")
                }

                override fun onConnectionStatusChange(status: ConnectionStatus) {
                    super.onConnectionStatusChange(status)
                    Log.d("log", "onConnectionStatusChange")
                }

                override fun onPaymentStatusChange(status: PaymentStatus) {
                    super.onPaymentStatusChange(status)
                    Log.d("log", "onPaymentStatusChange")
                }
            }
        )
```

- ***After this initialization**, you **can call the terminal instance** and
  work with it.*

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info, It help me .. But now I am struck with the error `Account not enabled for Tap on Mobile functionality`  Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: @Ajith I answered in your new question, please see the answer there
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74371800/7864454

Comment: Stripe tap to pay for android is in development and should appear soon.