# Android stripe terminal got struck with the error account not enabled for Tap on Mobile functionality

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe tap to pay on my NFC enabled mobile phone.
My reference link is https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=android&reader-type=tap-on-mobile

My app is build using kotlin and while implementing the feature on one of my activity, I got struck with the error `Account not enabled for Tap on Mobile functionality`

Can someone help me to fix this error, currently my stripe account is in test mode.

Note: One more thing I am trying to implement this feature from a country that is not in the list of Availability countries of terminal, Does this make any error , If so let me know if I can do the development globaly

I have added my code below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Terminal.initTerminal(
                            applicationContext,
                            LogLevel.VERBOSE,
                            TokenProvider(), // This will return stripe token (test account)
                            TerminalEventListener()
                         );


    val config = DiscoveryConfiguration(
                                            timeout         = 1000,
                                            discoveryMethod = DiscoveryMethod.LOCAL_MOBILE,
                                            isSimulated     = false,
                                            location        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                       );
    discoveryCancelable = Terminal.getInstance().discoverReaders(
            config,
            discoveryListener = object : DiscoveryListener {
                override fun onUpdateDiscoveredReaders(readers: List<Reader>) {

                    val firstReader = readers.first();
                    Log.d("Response Tap", "Finished onUpdateDiscoveredReaders");
                    val config = ConnectionConfiguration.LocalMobileConnectionConfiguration("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                    Terminal.getInstance().connectLocalMobileReader(
                        firstReader,
                        config,
                        object : ReaderCallback {
                            override fun onSuccess(reader: Reader) {
                                // I guess here the mobile will wait for card to tap on my mobile 
                                Log.d("Response Tap", "Connected to mobile device")
                            }
                            override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException) {
                                Log.d("Response Tap", "Error ReaderCallback : "+e.errorMessage) 
                                // Error ReaderCallback : Account not enabled for Tap on Mobile functionality

                            }
                        }
                    );

                }
            },
            object : Callback {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                Log.d("Response Tap", "Finished discovering readers")
            }
            override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException) {
                Log.d("Response Tap", "Error on Connection : "+e.errorMessage)
            }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that error, you will have to reach out to Stripe support to get your account enabled for that tap to pay feature. However, if your account is not located in one of the [Terminal-supported countries](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal), that's another issue. You can [request an invite](https://stripe.com/terminal#request-invite) to test out Terminal if you're located outside of the available countries.

Comment: Thanks, we will contact stripe team to do needful

One more thing https://stripe.com/in/terminal#request-invite  This will work on test mode as well, any documentation of filling the fields on that form. What all things we need to consider while filling the same, Some of the fields seems to be confuding

Comment: I don't think there's documentation. I'd just fill it out to the best of your ability. Looks like there's some optional fields there too.

Answer (score 1):

### ***Updated:***

I have the oficial response from the Stripe support

> I have confirmed that Stripe is having an upcoming release to enable businesses with Tap to Pay in Android. It's currently on private beta, hence you're only able to find documentations about Tap to Pay on iOS.

*This tells us that at the moment stripe tap to pay is not available on android, but support will be coming soon*

---

It seems to me that this is only available on iPhones and for the US region. The documentation describes this in more detail, the link can be found in more detail.

**(US / iPhone)** [Tap to pay on iPhone](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader/tap-to-pay-on-iphone)

I did not find information about this functionality in the android application, here most likely the support service would give you a clearer answer.

Comment: So you mean currently I cannot use Tap to Pay on Android Mobile phones with NFC support? But they are providing the android packages `com.stripe:stripeterminal-localmobile`, so obviously it should work on android phones as well ?

Comment: @Ajith I have updated my answer, you can check it out. In short - for now, stripe tap to pay for android is in development and should appear soon

Comment: What about in case of stripe beta account? android tap to pay is not available for stripe beta as well?

Comment: It is in private beta now, you cannot try to use it in private beta